# how to convert Object into any type in this situation

Tags: angular

So I have the following problem, I need to pass the data Object into this method but the problem is that it says it doesn't have the hits property, usually I would just do (data:any) but since I also need the news data I can't, any way to solve this?

```
public getDataByPage(contentType: string, pageNum: number): void {
    this.http.get(`https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=${contentType}&page=${pageNum}&hitsPerPage=16`).pipe(
      take(1),
      withLatestFrom(this.news$),
      tap(([data, news]) =>{
        this.parseNewsData([...news, ...data.hits]);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve you problem?
`this.parseNewsData([...news, ...(data as any).hits]);`

a better solution would be:
`this.http.get<any>('https://hn.algolia.com.....`

or
 `this.http.get<{hits:number}>('https://hn.algolia.com.....`

so `data` will have the correct type

Comment: it did, thank you, I still have a lot to learn

Comment: I edited my answer with a better solution

Comment: Oh yeah that looks a lot better, thanks